# How to manipulate a image like a Matrix using OpenCV?

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I need to develop a method to find the distance of a red line and the bottom of the image.
I already isolate the red line in hsv using some examples...
I know how to do this using MatLab but now i have to use the opencv :s
Someone can tell me how to do this?

Comment: You need to add more details of your question. If possible, upload a sample image in imageshack.us and provide link here.

Comment: Images are represented as matrices in OpenCV and anywhere. `cv::Mat img = imread("myImage.jpg");` will give you a matrix.

Comment: and how to access any element of the matrix?
its like img[x,y]? to do if (img[x,y,1]>155) {distance = y - img->width}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access each pixel value of the image in following way.

```
IplImage* img=cvLoadImage("your_image.jpg");
int pixelVal;
for(int x=0;x<img->height;x++){
for(int y=0;y<img->width;y++){
    pixelVal=((uchar*)(img->imageData + img->widthStep*x))[y];
}
}
```

in here,

> img->imageData returns a pointer to starting memory location of the image
>
> img->widthStep is the number of bytes in a image row

we access the each pixel value and cast using unsigned char pointer to get int value.

Comment: Thanks man!
And how can i access the hue using this?
Sry my ignorance.

Comment: first you have to convert image into HSV format using cvCvtImage(source,dest,CV_BGR2HSV). And then try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642097/how-to-set-hue-value-of-some-pixel-with-opencv